# Translating Windows.forms.Keys to real local keyboard value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use the namespace Windows.Forms.Keys

I would like to be able to catch and use some special like characters like é,è,à,ç, but when the program fire the event KeyDown, the KeyEventArg just return me the value "D1" to "D9".

What could I do to get the real char associated to these keys ?

Comment: A KeyDown event is a very different thing from a character being typed.  If Ctrl is held down at the same time for instance, that's not a character etc.  It relates to the actual physical key, which can be quite different to the effect that key will have if an input box happens to be focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use `KeyPress` instead of `KeyDown`.

`KeyDown` is really designed to work with the physical layout of the keyboard (well, the logical layout of the physica... forget it :D).  This is very different from the character that given physical key represents.

On the other hand `KeyPress` is all about characters being input from the keyboard, rather than keys being pressed, really. Note how `KeyPress` supports features like <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + `someKey` and char repetition etc.

If you really need to use `KeyDown`/`KeyUp`, you'll have to emulate the way windows keyboard system works to determine the char to output (for example, if you're making a keyboard mapping screen for a game or something like that). You can use the ToAscii WinAPI method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316.aspx).

Apart from that, you still have to understand the meaning of the key combinations - for example, on my keyboard, if I press <kbd>1</kbd>, I get `+`. If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, I get `1`. If I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, I get `!`. Which of those do you care about? Maybe <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> should be interpreted as `1` (what `KeyPress` does). Maybe it should be interpreted as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (the easiest, you already have that). And maybe it should be interpreted as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, the way it's usually used for hotkey bindings or keyboard mappings in games.

It should be pretty obvious by now that this is actually far from trivial. You need some mechanism to interpret the "raw" input data - and different interpretations make different sense for different initial conditions. You're basically asking for a mixed approach between the two obvious options - you're mixing virtual keys and "real" characters.

Comment: Well, thanks, I was on the wrong way. I guess I should just fire the 2 event if I want to intercept characters AND functionnality keys ?

Comment: @GlorfSf That really depends a lot on what you're actually trying to do. Why are you trying to capture characters / keypresses?

Comment: to make it simple, I must observe some user's actions, like typing a text or clicking somewhere, to make a program able to imitate these sames actions later. I need to catch functionnal keys like F1-F9, tab, and stuff like these, and I would help a lot if could have the exact text the user wanted to type too.

Comment: @GlorfSf Ah, right, don't do that. That's what UI automation is for - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. If you're still on Winforms, you'll probably have to resort to logging the messages processed in `WndProc` (with some filtering, probably). It's pretty easy to replay the messages when needed - that's basically how macroes in e.g. Excel work. Windows has GUI automation built in :)